# JTextPane getBaseline method returns -1

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane

I draw a textlayout in JTextPane. However I couldn't get right position of textlayout for y axis.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class CustomTextPane extends JTextPane {
    private final Font myFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 16);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //Drawing hint text

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout jTextLayout = new TextLayout("My Text", myFont, frc);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        int nBaseLine = getBaseline(getWidth(), getHeight());
        jTextLayout.draw(g2, 10, nBaseLine);

        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

The getBaseline method returns -1 for JTextPane.

But when I use this way for JTextField, then the getBaseLine method gets right value.

Why does baseline method return -1? How can I get the right value of baseline to draw my textlayout at the right position?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and add exactly what you want to know to it. The last paragraph seems to trail off and looks a bit unfinished, too. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I have edited my last paragraph

Comment: I don't know what the getBaseLineMethod does but I'm not sure it makes sense to use getWidth() and getHeight() as parameters given that a text pane displays multiple lines of text, so how can you get a baseline for all lines of text? The height of each line of text may be different. Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve. If we know the requirement (not your attempted solution) we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

As [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) already commented, the baseline of a single line of text makes more sense than a rectangle that can contain multiple lines of text (`JTextPane`).

When you call the `getBaseline` method for a `JTextField`, it calls the `JComponent.getBaseline` method, which leads to a call of the `BasicTextFieldUI.getBaseline` method. In this last method, the baseline is actually calculated.

When you call the `getBaseline` method for a `JTextPane`, it calls the `JComponent.getBaseline` method, which eventually leads to a call of the `ComponentUI.getBaseline` method. Here the three parameters are checked. If one of the parameters is incorrect, an exception is thrown; otherwise, the value -1 is returned.